# Is it possible to dynamically write data in flume

Tags: flume

I currently have a table which contains a column that indicates which table the row needs to be landed to. I was wondering if I would be able to dynamically assign the rows to their proper tables based on that column using flume. I looked into multiplexing, but it looks like the channels need to be statically configured when creating the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via a Custom Channel Selector. Alternatively, if you're using the KafkaSink, the event will be written to a topic if there is an event field named "topic", so you can use that for content based routing.